# Connection string for ODBC to get connection to the IBM isereis DB2

Tags: asp.net, odbc

I need to find odbc driver or provider to connect with IBM iseries Db2 through ODBC.
When I run my application I get a Keyword not supported : Provider. Can any one help me to
do connection with my IBMiseries Db2 database by using ODBC Connection String. 
Thanks.